# Reinstall system apps after removal

Tags: 2.2-froyo, root-access, gallery, system-apps

I rooted my phone and, perhaps over-zealously, removed many of the system apps which I deemed junk.

But, now I'm trying to restore one of the apps I removed, but simply restoring the file to the `/system/app` directory and giving the right permissions (`rw-r--r--` to `root:root`) does not allow me to use the app on my phone.

I am trying to restore the *Gallery3d.apk* app file (from a backup) to my LG P509 phone. I am not sure if this solution will have general application or will only apply to this particular app.

I have already tried copying the app to the user-accessible storage and trying to install it as a User app, but the install fails.

How do I restore this app (or these types of apps) so that my phone will be able to use it again?

Comment: You probably need to reboot after putting the file back in `/system/app`. Or otherwise force it to refresh the list of installed apps (which maybe the `pm` command can do, not sure)